# php mySQL connection not initialized

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm running two test XAMPP servers, both with similar `PDO Connection` classes

First:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Clase que envuelve una instancia de la clase PDO
 * para el manejo de la base de controladores
 */

require_once 'login_mysql.php';


class ConexionBD
{

    /**
     * Única instancia de la clase
     */
    private static $db = null;

    /**
     * Instancia de PDO
     */
    private static $pdo;

    final private function __construct()
    {
        try {
            // Crear nueva conexión PDO
            self::obtenerBD();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            // Manejo de excepciones
        }


    }

    /**
     * Retorna en la única instancia de la clase
     * @return ConexionBD|null
     */
    public static function obtenerInstancia()
    {
        if (self::$db === null) {
            self::$db = new self();
        }
        return self::$db;
    }

    /**
     * Crear una nueva conexión PDO basada
     * en las constantes de conexión
     * @return PDO Objeto PDO
     */
    public function obtenerBD()
    {
        if (self::$pdo == null) {
            self::$pdo = new PDO(
                'mysql:dbname=' . BASE_DE_DATOS .
                ';host=' . NOMBRE_HOST . ";",
                USUARIO,
                CONTRASENA,
                array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
            );

            // Habilitar excepciones
            self::$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }

        return self::$pdo;
    }

    /**
     * Evita la clonación del objeto
     */
    final protected function __clone()
    {
    }

    function _destructor()
    {
        self::$pdo = null;
    }
}
```

Second (this one doesn't work):

```
    <?php
/**
 * Clase que envuelve una instancia de la clase PDO
 * para el manejo de la base de datos
 */

require_once 'mysql_login.php';


class Database
{

    /**
     * Única instancia de la clase
     */
    private static $db = null;

    /**
     * Instancia de PDO
     */
    private static $pdo;

    final private function __construct()
    {
        try {
            // Crear nueva conexión PDO
            self::getDb();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            // Manejo de excepciones
        }


    }

    /**
     * Retorna en la única instancia de la clase
     * @return Database|null
     */
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (self::$db === null) {
            self::$db = new self();
        }
        return self::$db;
    }

    /**
     * Crear una nueva conexión PDO basada
     * en los datos de conexión
     * @return PDO Objeto PDO
     */
    public function getDb()
    {
        if (self::$pdo == null) {
            self::$pdo = new PDO(
                'mysql:dbname=' . DATABASE .
                ';host=' . HOSTNAME .
                ';port:63343;',
                USERNAME,
                PASSWORD,
                array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
            );

            // Habilitar excepciones
            self::$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }

        return self::$pdo;
    }

    /**
     * Evita la clonación del objeto
     */
    final protected function __clone()
    {
    }

    function _destructor()
    {
        self::$pdo = null;
    }
}

?>
```

And for some reason the second connection is not resolved. Any ideas why this might be?

Both files are on different directories and are referenced by different, isolated files.

**EDIT**: Error returned

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/estudiantesServer/Database.php:60 Stack trace: 
    #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/estudiantesServer/Database.php(60): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', 'root', Array) 
    #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/estudiantesServer/Database.php(27): Database->getDb() 
    #2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/estudiantesServer/Database.php(42): Database->__construct() 
    #3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/estudiantesServer/estudiantes.php(26): Database::getInstance() 
    #4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/estudiantesServer/getEstudiantes.php(10): Estudiantes::getAll() 
    #5 {main}
```

Comment: what error did you get????

Comment: The second one specifies a port number for the mysql server. I guess the server is not configured to listen on that port but the error message will give us the explanation.

Comment: I don't know if it's normal or not, but in the first class you require `login_mysql.php` ans in the second one : `mysql_login.php`

Comment: Edited response with error output

Comment: What is the output of these commands: `netstat -tulpn | grep :63343` and `netstat -tulpn | grep :3306` on the server?

Comment: `:63343` doesn't return anything and `:3306` returns `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

Comment: Are you sure about the port number used in your second class ? Usually, mysql listens on the `3306`. Try to replace `63343` by `3306` if you taked this example on the net.